# IPN not posting to database ( IPN Simulator )

Tags: php, mysqli, paypal, paypal-ipn

Here is the relevant code ( **Snippet from IPN page** ):

```
 if($payment_status=='Completed'){

    $txn_id_check = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT 'transaction_id' FROM 'payment' WHERE 'transaction_id'='".$txn_id."'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($txn_id_check)!=1){

        if($receiver_email=='fortunefilly@hotmail.com'){

            if($payment_amount=='9.99' && $payment_currency=='GBP'){

                // add txn_id to db
                $query = "INSERT INTO payment (transaction_id, payment_status, users_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
                $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
                $statement->bind_param('sss',$txn_id, $payment_status,$id);
                if($statement->execute()){
                print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
                }else{
                die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
                }
                $statement->close();
                // update premium to 1 

                $update_premium = mysqli_query("UPDATE 'users' SET is_member ='1' WHERE 'id' ='".$id."'");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*As you can see I am following the comments that were given to me by paypals sample code.*

There is a problem with inserting into the database but am unsure as to the problem.

Comment: Your `SELECT` query says `WHERE 'transaction_id'='$txn_id'='tx_id'`, are you allowed to do a query like that in MySQL?

Comment: missing execution. prepare->bind->execute

Comment: whoops that was a mistake haha. still the problem persists. I edited it

Comment: I edited again, still problem persists

Comment: added syntax error extra `)`

Comment: Edited again, problem still!

Comment: debug debug debug, echo everyting

Comment: Yeah I'm unsure how to as it's an IPN simulator I'm using